# how to make woocommerce payment for registered users

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Requirement :
I have a custom requirement where anyone can enroll for a single course.

The tool I have to use is woocommerce with a custom woocommerce payment plugin.

These are the steps that a user will go through:-

Step 1: User registers

Step 2: The user is redirected to the payment page once payment is completed.

Step 3: User gets enrolled.

Now the issue is that woocommerce by default has payment for a virtual and physical product.

Please suggest a suitable method to implement this in woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

```
function control_payment( $args ) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // unset your payment
    }
    return $args;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'control_payment' );
```

Or you can use something like this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'my_paypal_disable_manager' );

function my_paypal_disable_manager( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {
      unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
   } 
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

(https://businessbloomer.com/disable-payment-gateway-specific-user-role-woocommerce/)

Comment: Thankyou for the support.I have a register form and from that a user gets registered.So my question is that in woocommerce can we add a course as product and set the registered user as an order once the user gets registered.

Comment: Yes you can do that.